# Horror movie where it’s really hot outside enough to where they have to wear fire suits

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I remember this movie I think on Netflix. The cover art was of someone in a [silver fire suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_proximity_suit).  It was a horror movie, where it's really hot outside, enough to where they have to wear fire suits.  It was in English, on Earth, and not animated.

Comment: Can you remember any more details? Was it set on a planet? Earth? In Space? Was it animated or live action? Engliosh language or dubbed? You can take a tour of the site and learn how to better phrase your question here... https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Fire proximity suits like these? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_proximity_suit

Comment: Was it post-apocalyptic? Did the protagonists start in a giant (largely CGI) city, then travel on a bus?

Comment: You know i am somehow suspecting this film is Sunshine.

Comment: @dominicfonde - Not set on Earth

Comment: @Valorum so my suspicion about sunshine was totally off the mark! glad the details about the fire suit and it being set on earth were added. They weren't there when I commented. I definitely dont know what this one is though!